# sbt fails to start due to org.webjars.npm#graceful-readlink;1.0.0

Tags: java, macos, sbt

I'm having troubles starting sbt on java-play 2.6 project with following errors:

sbt.ResolveException:

**unresolved dependency: org.webjars.npm#graceful-readlink;1.0.0: not found**

**unresolved dependency: org.webjars.npm#minimatch;[2,3),[3,4): not found**

Dependencies to these libraries come from plugin "sbt-reactjs" % "0.6.8"

Already tried deleting, reinstalling things (like : re-install sbt, delete node modules, cleaning ivy, sbt caches), and still getting frustrated with this error.

Environment: Mac OS X, ProductVersion:  10.13.1

Any ideas will be very much appreciated :) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a similar issue with the org.webjars.npm#minimatch;[2,3),[3,4): not found on a existing Play project that worked just fine earlier, still trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to overcomes the issue is:

- decrease sbt version to 0.13.15
- adding dependency overrides to *plugins.sbt*

```scala
dependencyOverrides += "org.webjars.npm" % "minimatch" % "3.0.4"
dependencyOverrides += "org.webjars.npm" % "graceful-readlink" % "1.0.1"
```